# How do I create a member function in a class that returns a value that is the type of an object of that class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

Here's the question:

Define a class called Month that is an abstract data type for a month. Your class will
have one member variable of type int to represent a month (1 for January, 2 for
February, and so forth). Include all the following member functions: a constructor
to set the month using the first three letters in the name of the month as three
arguments, a constructor to set the month using an integer as an argument (1 for
January, 2 for February, and so forth), a default constructor, an input function that
reads the month as an integer, an input function that reads the month as the first
three letters in the name of the month, an output function that outputs the month
as an integer, an output function that outputs the month as the first three letters
in the name of the month, and a member function that returns the next month as
a value of type Month . Embed your class definition in a test program.

Here's my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Month
    {
    public:
Month(char firstLetter, char secondLetter, char thirdLetter);
//Initializes month according to arguments for first 3 letters

Month(int month_number);
//Initializes month according to argument for integer between 1 and 12

Month();
//Initializes month to January

void input_integer();//Reads month as integer
void input_letter();//Reads month as first 3 letters in the name of month
int letters_to_integer(char firstLetter, char secondLetter, char thirdLetter);
//Converts first 3 letters of the month to integer equivalent of the month
string integer_to_letters(int month_number);
//Converts month integer to the first 3 letters of the name of the month
void output_integer();//Outputs the month as an integer
void output_letter();//Outputs the month as first 3 letters of the name of the month

void next_month();//Returns the next month in letters
    private:
int month_number;//Represents the month as an integer
string month_letters;//Represents the month in terms of its first 3 letters
char firstLetter, secondLetter, thirdLetter;
int next_month_number;//Represents the next month as an integer
    };

    int main()
    {
Month month1('m', 'a', 'y'), month2(7), month3;
cout<<"Object month1 is initialized as follows:\n";
month1.output_letter();
cout<<"Object month2 is initialized as follows:\n";
month2.output_letter();
cout<<"Object month3 is initialized as follows:\n";
month3.output_letter();

cout<<"Enter the first 3 letters of the month\n";
month3.input_letter();
cout<<"That month expressed as in integer is:\n";
month3.output_integer();
cout<<endl;


cout<<"Enter the month as an integer between 1 and 12:\n";
month3.input_integer();
cout<<"That is equivalent to the month of:\n";
month3.output_letter();
cout<<"in letters\n";
cout<<"The next month is: \n";
month3.next_month();
cout<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
    }

    Month::Month(char firstLetter, char secondLetter, char thirdLetter)
    {
month_number = letters_to_integer(firstLetter, secondLetter, thirdLetter);
month_letters = integer_to_letters(month_number);
    }

    Month::Month(int month_number)
    {
month_letters = integer_to_letters(month_number);
    }

    Month::Month()
    {
month_number = 1;
month_letters = "Jan\n";
    }

    void Month::input_integer()
    {
cin>>month_number;
month_letters = integer_to_letters(month_number);
next_month_number = month_number + 1;
    }

    void Month::input_letter()
    {
cin>>firstLetter>>secondLetter>>thirdLetter;
month_number = letters_to_integer(firstLetter, secondLetter, thirdLetter);
    }

    void Month::output_letter()
    {
cout<<month_letters;
    }

    void Month::output_integer()
    {
cout<<month_number;
    }

    int Month::letters_to_integer(char firstLetter, char secondLetter, char      thirdLetter)
    {
if ((firstLetter == 'j') && (secondLetter == 'a') && (thirdLetter == 'n'))
{
    month_number = 1;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'f') && (secondLetter == 'e') && (thirdLetter == 'b'))
{
    month_number = 2;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'm') && (secondLetter == 'a') && (thirdLetter == 'r'))
{
    month_number = 3;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'a') && (secondLetter == 'p') && (thirdLetter == 'r'))
{
    month_number = 4;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'm') && (secondLetter == 'a') && (thirdLetter == 'y'))
{
    month_number = 5;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'j') && (secondLetter == 'u') && ( thirdLetter == 'n'))
{
    month_number = 6;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'j') && (secondLetter == 'u') && (thirdLetter == 'l'))
{
    month_number = 7;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'a') && (secondLetter == 'u') && (thirdLetter == 'g'))
{
    month_number = 8;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 's') && (secondLetter == 'e') && (thirdLetter == 'p'))
{
    month_number = 9;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'o') && (secondLetter == 'c') && (thirdLetter == 't'))
{
    month_number = 10;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'n') && (secondLetter == 'o') && (thirdLetter == 'v'))
{
    month_number = 11;
}
else if ((firstLetter == 'd') && (secondLetter == 'e') && (thirdLetter == 'c'))
{
    month_number = 12;
}
return month_number;
     }

    string Month::integer_to_letters(int month_number)
    {
string month_letters;

switch (month_number)
{
    case 1:
        month_letters = "Jan\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        month_letters = "Feb\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        month_letters = "Mar\n";
        break;
    case 4:
        month_letters = "Apr\n";
        break;
    case 5:
        month_letters = "May\n";
        break;
    case 6:
        month_letters = "Jun\n";
        break;
    case 7:
        month_letters = "Jul\n";
        break;
    case 8:
        month_letters = "Aug\n";
        break;
    case 9:
        month_letters = "Sep\n";
        break;
    case 10:
        month_letters = "Oct\n";
        break;
    case 11:
        month_letters = "Nov\n";
        break;
    case 12:
        month_letters = "Dec\n";
        break;
    default:
        month_letters = "Invalid integer for month";
        break;

}
return month_letters;
    }

    void Month::next_month()
    {
cout<<integer_to_letters(next_month_number);
    }
```

Sorry its indented all strange but this is what I have. My code runs just fine. The only thing I don't get how to do is the last part of the question which asks to create "a member function that returns the next month as
a value of type Month." I am not understanding this at all. So in code I just output the string that is the next month. Please help me with this part. In class we just covered classes and this is the assignment. Please be as simple and basic as possible. I'm not too familiar with c++ or programming in general.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand about the question so I'm not sure where to start explaining.

Comment: how can i create a function that returns the next month as a value of type month? i really don't get what it means to return as a value of type month because month is a class with many types and functions. how can i return the next month which is an integer or string, as a value of the type from the class month?

Comment: A class is a type. You're supposed to return an object, not an integer or string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"and a member function that returns the next month as a value of type Month"

So basically your class `Month` needs to have a function that returns the following month as an object of type `Month`. For instance, if I had an object of `Month` that was equal to "June", and I called a function... call it `getNextMonth()` it should return a `Month` object equal to "July".

So your month class needs to have a function, presumably in the `public` section defined as `Month getNextMonth();` I'll leave you to figure out how to define that function, but I would suggest reading up on "Copy constructors" and what happens when you return a class instance by value. Your class doesn't require any "deep copies" of any variables, so the default copy constructor should be fine, but it's good to know what is actually happening when your code runs.

Comment: we haven't learned about copy constructors yet in class so I think I'm supposed to do this problem without that. But if you look at my code, its too long to paste here but referring to one of input functions: 
void Month::input_integer()

In this input function I determine what the next month is as an integer. I can just add another line that converts this into a string of the month. Subsequently,  how can I take this string, put it into the Month getNextMonth(); function and then in the main function, call the Month getNextMonth() function and output this value?

Answer (score 0):

As Basic As Possible :
Return types:-written before the function name when you are defining or declaring a function ex- int main();. Instead of using void or int your question demands you to use the return type as your class ie 'Month' that you have defined.So instead of returning nothing or an int you will be returning an object of class Month

Comment: thanks for that straightforward answer.But the next month in this case is either an integer or string. How can I translate that into something thats returned by an object of class month? And conceptually, what happens when you return an object? Does it output all the values of the variables and values determined by the functions in the object?

Comment: See this is what you do, you save the values in a data member of the class by initializing an object. Say Month m; and save data in m. datavariable further you return m.  And printing the next month,  ill let you figure that part on your own.